# A conceptual question about the limitation of the MA processes

Tags: arima, econometrics, stochastic-processes, moving-average

We know that linear time-series techniques are frequently used in macroeconometrics. The Wold Representation Theorem states that any covariance-stationary process may be expressed as an MA process plus some deterministic term.

One limitation is that the order q must be too large in order to be useful in many applications and ARMA models represent the characteristics of MA processes with infinite lag order well.

So I would like to understand better two points:

1. the need for $q$ to be too large in order to be useful
2. How the features of MA processes with infinite lag order are well captured by ARMA models?